# Как взять значение локальной переменной из .on jquery при клике, в глобальную область видимости?

Tags: javascript

```
var name = 0;

$('.login').on('click', '.login__name', function(){
name = 1;
});

console.log(name); Выведет 0 без клика, и при клике тоже 0
```

Comment: у вас сначала в лог выводится, а потом вы кликаете

Comment: @teran дело в том что переменная name не меняет своего значения при клике. а должна, потому что я задал ее в глобальной области видвимости

Comment: Она меняется. Повесьте console.log на клик для проверки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измените название переменной. Вы наблюдаете конфликт между Вашей переменной и `window.name`.

```js
var name1 = 0;

$('.login').on('click', '.login__name', function() {
  name1 = 1;console.log(name1);
});

console.log(name1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="login">
  <button class="login__name">Change</button>
</div>

<button onclick="console.log(name1)">Check</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, долго думал над этим :D